# cannot import pygame on pycharm - linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pycharm

I'm trying to import pygame on pycharm, i already have installed pygame and it runs when i execute programs by command line, but when i try to use it from pycharm it doesn't work. I tried to add it to the project interpreter but an error occurs:

`Non-zero exit code (1)
Collecting Pygame`
`No matching distribution found for Pygame the requirement Pygame (from versions: )`

Also tried`pip install Pygame` from command line but occurs:
`Collecting Pygame
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Pygame (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for Pygame`

I'm running python 3.5 and pygame v1.9.1 and pycharm is updated.
Os: Linux Mint 17.3

Comment: type `import pygame` at the top of a python file in pycharm ... when pycharm underlines it in red, click it so your cursor is on the word `pygame` (ie if you typed something it would make pygame say a different word) ... hit alt+enter, select the option to "install missing package" ... pycharm will make sure it is available for the interpreter you are using ...

Comment: To install it for python 3 you have to use `pip3 install`

Comment: always the same error: Non-zero exit code(1)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by uninstalling and reinstalling pygame making sure to correctly solve all dependencies as explained by the [wiki](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/CompileUbuntu?parent=Compilation)